# How to determine if a given Integer is in a particular Enum?

Tags: .net, enums

In VB.NET, even with `Option Strict` on, it's possible to pass an Enum around as an Integer.

In my particular situation, someone's using an enum similar to this:

```
Public Enum Animals
    Monkey = 1
    Giraffe = 2
    Leopard = 3
    Elephant = 4
End Enum
```

But they are passing it around as an Integer so they can set a value of -1 to be "No animal" (without having to include "No animal" in the Enum itself), i.e.:

```
Public Sub MakeAnimalJump(animalType As Int32)
    If animalType < 1 Then
        ' Clearly not an animal...
    Else
        ' Make that animal jump...
    End If
End Sub
```

However, later on, they're asking for it to be an Animals type again.  My question is, aside from a) changing the Enum to include a "None" value or b) cycling through each value in the Enum using `[Enum].GetValues(...)`, is there an easy way to work out whether a given Integer maps to a value in the enum or not?

I was hoping there might be an [Enum].TryParse or something, but it doesn't look like there is.

EDIT: As some of you have suggested, there is an Enum.TryParse in .NET 4.  Unfortunately, the project in question must still support Windows Server 2000, so we can't use the latest .NET Framework (hopefully we'll be able to drop support for Windows Server 2000 soon..!).

Comment: Enum.TryParse() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835389.aspx

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Although .NET 4.0 introduced the `Enum.TryParse` method you should not use it for this specific scenario. In .NET an enumeration has an underlying type which can be any of the following (`byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`). By default is `int`, so any value that is a valid `int` is also a valid enumeration value.

This means that `Enum.TryParse<Animal>("-1", out result)` reports success even though `-1` is not associated to any specified enumeration value.

As other have noted, for this scenarios, you must use `Enum.IsDefined` method.

Sample code (in C#):

```
enum Test { Zero, One, Two }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test value;
    bool tryParseResult = Enum.TryParse<Test>("-1", out value);
    bool isDefinedResult = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Test), -1);

    Console.WriteLine("TryParse: {0}", tryParseResult); // True
    Console.WriteLine("IsDefined: {0}", isDefinedResult); // False
}
```

Comment: IsDefined doesn't seem to work if the value is an actual string. E.g. "One". IsDefined returns false

Answer (score 7):

One option is to try something like this (in C#):

```
bool isTheValueInTheEnum = System.Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Animals), animalType);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) in .NET 4.

Although [Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) probably suits your needs better.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I had no idea there was an Enum.TryParse in .NET 4.  Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that the project is in .NET 2 only at present, as it still supports Windows Server 2000 (eventually, we'll move on from that, I hope...).  I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

There is `[Enum].IsDefined` which if try means your `[Enum].Parse` should succeed.

You should also be able to add a `None = -1` option to the Enum

In my enums I tend to use a pattern like:

```
public enum Items
{
    Unknown = 0,
    One,
    Two, 
    Three,
}
```

So that a default int -> Enum will return `Unknown`

---

In .NET 4 there is a `TryParse` method too.

Comment: There is Enum.TryParse() in .NET 4.