# How to compare to a collection of constants in VB.Net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, constants

I have a user entered value to check against a set of reserved numbers for validation. The set of reserved numbers never changes. Thus, being a C programmer at heart, I popped the reserved numbers into an array and reached for my `const` blaster.

```vb
Const ReservedAddresses() As Byte = {10, 12, 75} 'I wish...
```

However, annoyingly VS informed me thusly:

> Constants must be of an intrinsic or enumerated type, not a class, structure, type parameter, or array type.

How then should one correctly contain a set of unchanging numbers through which one would like to loop, or otherwise check against, at some point in the future?

Comment: A C language *const* has very little to do with a VB.NET Const.  Use Shared ReadOnly instead.

Comment: FWIW, I suggest changing your array declaration from C-style to .NET style: in other words, put the `()` behind the *type*, not the variable. Both are valid but one doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Normally I would in VB, not sure what came over me - my C mind must be taking over altogether! :0

Comment: @HansPassant `ReadOnly` does nothing to stop the values on the array being changed. See James Thorpe's comment below

Comment: I made no such promise of course.  ImmutableArray tends to be overkill.

Comment: What about using an `Enum` to define the values, and something like [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996052/how-to-determine-if-a-given-integer-is-in-a-particular-enum) when you need to check them?

Comment: @JamesThorpe As that link suggests I can define them as enum values and use Enum.IsDefined() to produce the required effect. 
It amazes me that this is the only way to properly achieve such a simple task in VB.

Comment: @Toby Take a look at [Konrad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34858578/791010) - I think it's probably the best you can get if you truly want an unchanging list with simple syntax to check the values later on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in other answers, `Const` works quite differently in .NET, and is generally not terribly useful.

You could use

```
Private Shared ReadOnly m_ReservedAddresses = {10, 12, 75}
Public Shared ReadOnly ReservedAddresses As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Integer)(m_ReservedAddresses)
```

But honestly I would probably simply use a `ReadOnly` array.

Comment: I’ve changed the answer, the first version used the [collection initialiser syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) but since that requires an `Add` extension method, it probably doesn’t work with the `ReadOnlyCollection` (I’m not on Windows so I can’t check).

Answer (score 3):

> Constants must be of an intrinsic type (`Boolean`, `Byte`, `Date`, `Decimal`,
>   `Double`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Object`, `SByte`, `Short`, `Single`, `String`, `UInteger`,
>   `ULong`, or `UShort`), or an `Enum` type based on one of the integral types. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csfwb0sw.aspx))

Why not readonly instead?

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ReservedAddresses() As Byte = { 10, 12, 75 }
```

Update: Per your unchanging values requirement, an `IList` will do the trick:

```
Public ReadOnly ReservedAddresses As IList(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)() From { 10, 12, 75 }.AsReadOnly()
```

...but @Konrad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34858578/4302070) is cleaner.

Comment: That [doesn't stop](http://imgur.com/x8S8CkS) you from changing the values contained within the array, which is what the OP appears to be after.

Comment: that will not make the values in the array ReadOnly.  It just means you can reassign the entire array as in `ReservedAddresses = {1, 21, 7}`

Comment: Because this does not stop the values being changed at all, á la `ReservedAddresses(0) = 11` works with no problem :(

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. This is the best you can get. Yes, it’s not great. But that’s a language restriction (I mean, sure, one could stuff them into a read-only container … but nobody would do this in such a situation).

Answer (score 1):

This would do pretty much *what* you want, just not exactly how you want to do it:

```
Class ReservedAddresses
    Public Shared ReadOnly A As Int32 = 10
    Public Shared ReadOnly B As Int32 = 12
    Public Shared ReadOnly C As Int32 = 75
End Class
```

It lacks the array wrapper, but meaningful names would seem to be clearer than `ReservedAddresses(0)`.

Comment: How would one then check against the values? Say I have value `x` I then need something like `If x <> .A AndAlso x <> .B AndAlso...` which is no better than just using the numbers directly as literals, no?

Comment: Correct except they would be grouped together with a meaningful name (not unlike an Enum).   There is a little less repetition in  `ReservedAddress.FooName` vs `ReservedAddressFooName`.  It is just an option; there isnt a direct version of what you want.